# How to change MySQL data directory to Google Drive location?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to change the data directory to a Google Drive location mapped to my explorer through Google File Stream. I created a new folder where I would like the new data directory to be:

G:\My Drive\mysqlGD

So I stop the server in the workbench at the "startup/shutdown" tab, went into the my.ini file (via notepad++) and commented out the old C:\ location and typed in:

datadir=G:/My Drive/mysqlGD

When I restart the server I get this error:

Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) (2003)

If I comment out the G:\ and back in the C:\ it works fine again with no error.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Or am I just missing something here?

Comment: You really, *really* do not want to put your MySQL data directory on Google Drive.

Comment: Really a very bad idea.

Comment: The logic behind this decision is because I get free unlimited data via my university's subscription to the service. I am fully aware of how much data it will fill up with. This is intended as a one time use. I have an equity options .CSV that is about 90gb I am trying to create a db of then chop it down via mysql until it's manageable in excel.

Comment: It will still take up space on *your* drive, and any change to the database is likely to cause the *entire* thing to be re-uploaded. You may have unlimited data via Drive, but there's a very good chance you'll be cut off for abuse of the service. Or your university may tell you to stop using 90GB of bandwidth every few minutes.

Comment: Thank you I see, I am definitely new to all of this but I understand. My main issue is I don't have enough hdd space, so I think I will get an external hd and see if I can do it from there instead.

Comment: Yeah, Google Drive won't fix that. You still need the space locally.